Small solutions to a system of linear inequalities over a finite field
For a finite integer field $\mathbb{Z}_q$, $q>2^\lambda$ is a prime, $\lambda\in\mathbb{N}$,
suppose that there are $l$ unknown variables, $(x_1,x_2,...,x_l)$, each of them belongs to a value range $\mathsf{Range}_x:=[0:2^{\frac{3\lambda}8}]$, and $\log(l)+\frac{3\lambda}8<\frac{\lambda}{2}$. The system of constraints are defined as belows, where $i\in[n]:=\{1,..,n\}$.
$\begin{cases}&(a_{i,1}x_1+a_{i,2}x_2+\cdots+a_{i,l}x_l+a_{i,l+1})\bmod{q}\in\mathsf{Range}_e\\&(a_{i,2}x_1+a_{i,3}x_2+\cdots+a_{i,l+1}x_l+a_{i,l+2})\bmod{q}\in\mathsf{Range}_e\\&...\\&(a_{i,n-l}x_1+a_{i,n-l+1}x_2+\cdots+a_{i,n-1}x_l+a_{i,n})\bmod{q}\in\mathsf{Range}_e&\end{cases}$
where $a_{i,j}\in\mathbb{Z}_q,\forall i\in[n],j\in[n]$ are known and the result of each formula belongs to $\mathsf{Range}_e:=[0:2^{\frac{\lambda}{2}}]$. That's to say, there are $n\times (n-l)$  constraint conditions to find $(x_1,x_2,...,x_l)$ over $\mathbb{Z}_q$, and each $x_k\in\mathsf{Range}_x$,$k\in[l]$. Note that, we assume that the solution must exist, our goal is to find the solution $(x_1,x_2,...,x_l)$.
Using the concept of a system of constraints to articulate my inquiry may lack rigor; however, I am seeking clarification on whether there exist polynomial time algorithms for solving the problem.
I initially considered using some linear programming algorithms to solve this problem, but the optimization objective was unclear. In additional, the linear programming algorithm for inequalities over finite fields is not entirely clear for me. As of now, the only approach I can think of is exhaustive search. However, if $\lambda$ is large, say $\lambda=128$, solving this problem in a reasonable cost becomes impractical due to its exponentially increasing complexity.

Have you tried studying lattice reduction methods?  The cryptographic literature might be particularly relevant.

@D.W. Yes, your understanding is correct. And I tried to study the lattice theory, knowing some lattice reduction algorithms, including Gauss reduction, LLL, BKG algorithms to solve specific problems, such as SVP, CVP and SIS. However, I cannot build a connection to these well-studied problems, furthermore, I have no idea how to solve my problem by these classical lattice reduction algorithms.

I would suggest trying lattice reduction methods.  I don't know whether they will work or not for the particular parameter settings you have listed, but I think they are a natural to try.  In particular, consider the following basis matrix:
$$B = \begin{bmatrix}
2^{\lambda/8}& & & & &a_{1,1} &a_{1,2} &\cdots &a_{1,l+1} &\cdots &a_{n,1} &\cdots &a_{n,l+1}\\
 &2^{\lambda/8}& & & &a_{1,2} &a_{1,3} &\cdots &a_{1,l+2} &\cdots &a_{n,2} &\cdots &a_{n,l+2}\\
   &&\ddots&&&          &\vdots&\\
 & & &2^{\lambda/8} &&a_{1,l} &a_{1,l+1} &\cdots &a_{1,n-1} &\cdots &a_{n,l} &\cdots &a_{n,n-1}\\
 & & & &2^{\lambda}&a_{1,l+1} &a_{1,l+2} &\cdots &a_{1,n} &\cdots &a_{n,l+1} &\cdots &a_{n,n}\\
 & & & & &q\\
 & & & & & & & & &\ddots\\
 & & & & & & & & & & & &q\\
K &K &\cdots &K &-2^{\lambda} &K &K &\cdots &K &\cdots &K &\cdots &K\\
\end{bmatrix}$$
where $K=-2^{\lambda/2-1}$ is an appropriately chosen large constant.
Consider the linear combination $t=[x_1,\dots,x_l,1,-b_1,\dots,-b_{(n-l)n},1]$.  It generates the vector $u=tB$.  Note that, if $b_1 = \lfloor (a_{1,1} x_1 + \dots + a_{1,l} x_l + a_{1,l+1})/q \rfloor$ etc., then $u$ is relatively short: its components are all at most $2^{\lambda/2-1}$ in absolute value, except that the $l+1$th component is 0.  In particular,
$$\|u\|_2\approx \sqrt{l \cdot 2^{\lambda-2} + (n-l)n \cdot 2^{\lambda-2}} \approx \sqrt{l + (n-l)n} \cdot 2^{\lambda/2-1}.$$
If we are lucky, lattice reduction (to find the shortest vector in this lattice) finds this particular vector $u$, revealing $t$ and thus the solution $x_1,\dots,x_l$.
I don't know whether $u$ is short enough to expect that $u$ is the shortest vector in the lattice or that lattice reduction will indeed solve the problem in practice, but you could give it a try.
See the following paper for a helpful introduction to the use of lattice reduction to solve similar problems:
A Gentle Tutorial for Lattice-Based Cryptanalysis.  Joseph Surin, Shaanan Cohney.  IACR ePrint 2023/032.

Thanks so much for showing me the way for my next research. Lattice theory is a bit tricky, but I'll keep working on solving the problem using lattice theory based on your clear perspective.
